# TBB task_groups without using stack

Tags: c++, tree, traversal, tbb

I would like to perform a post-order tree traversal in C++. The tree can be so deep that I cannot use recursion (it exhausts the stack). Instead I create an `std::stack<...>` that puts everything on the heap, and traverse the tree in a while loop rather than with function calls. This works great.

Now I would like to parallelize the whole process using TBB. I was thinking of creating a `task_group` at every node, and running the same `functor` on each of its children. But it occurs to me that this would run into the same problem with the tree depth I had before: running the `functor` on each node of the deepest path will eat away something from the stack until the whole thing runs out.

Is there a way out of this problem? Or am I imagining the whole thing; is there some magic behind `task_group::wait()` that avoids this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TBB documentation (about implicit continuation):

> Because the parent blocks, its thread’s stack cannot be popped yet.
>   The thread must be careful about what work it takes on, because
>   continually stealing and blocking could cause the stack to grow
>   without bound.

This is not exactly about that, but it shows that TBB is not using any stack magic to empty stack for currently blocked tasks. This means that you would get stack-overflows a bit later (spreaded among multiple thread's stacks) when using implicit continuation.

Using explicit continuation might solve the problem, but that depends heavily on internal TBB implementation of thread scheduler (which is not documented). There is a fair chance that it would work correctly - the only way to know is to either look through TBB sources amd see how task are handled, or write simple test program with small stack and look if something simple will be able to exhaust it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think explicit continuation is the way to go. If I understand continuation passing in TBB tutorial correctly, it should avoid my problem. Time to experiment, I suppose.

Comment: If you have any results of your experiments, post them here as well - I am also qurious ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment verifying you will need to use continuations for this. There is nothing magical about task_group::wait that would prevent it from consuming the stack.

task_group is in the ppl and you can use the task continuations described in the [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/03/09/tasks-and-continuations-available-for-download-today.aspx) and available in the ppl sample pack.

Comment: I know next to nothing about the world of Miscrosoft. Is there a connection between PPL and TBB?